# How can I set crystal report data source a database that's not connected to it?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, crystal-reports

Iam working on windows app using c# and using crystal report. My problem is that I need to configure my report to get data from the live database but I can't connect to it while developing the program.

Is there a way that I can configure crystal report with live database and connect when generate the exe and install it on the same network with live database?

Answer (score 0):

I know of a way to do this in Visual Studio, but if you are using one of the stand-alone SAP clients to develop the report this method won't help you.

In Visual Studio you want to add a DataSet to your project.  Don't implement this through code though, do this by adding a DataSet object to your project in the project explorer just like you would add a new class file.  Within this DataSet object you can create a DataTable with all of the same columns you will have in the database you plan to use.

This will allow you to design a crystal report using the dataTable within your DataSet as the database.  You won't be able to preview anything in the Crystal Report Designer though.

In your Visual Studio project you will need to build a dataset that has the same schema as the dataset and datatable you have defined as the database for your report.  Then you can assign the datatable within your dataset to the DataSource property of your crystal report at runtime.

I've mostly used this approach when consuming CSV data files as datasources for crystal reports in a system that had a terrible reporting system that could only produce text file outputs, but it could be used almost identically for what you are trying to accomplish, but instead of importing a CSV file, you will query your database at runtime time to get the data into a dataset that is assigned to DataSource property of the report.